# Matplotlib - Border around scatter plot points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/machine-learning-python).

I would like to use Matplotlib to create a scatter plot with points that are colored inside, but have a black border, such as this plot:

[image: photo]

However, when I copy the code exactly, I get this plot instead.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
colors = ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'white', 'red', 'lime', 'cyan', 'orange', 'gray']
for i in range(len(colors)):
    x = reduced_data_rpca[:, 0][digits.target == i]
    y = reduced_data_rpca[:, 1][digits.target == i]
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors[i])
plt.legend(digits.target_names, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.xlabel('First Principal Component')
plt.ylabel('Second Principal Component')
plt.title("PCA Scatter Plot")
plt.show()
```

I tried adjusting the style, but that didn't help.

Comment: If I were to take a guess; `marker='o'` but you haven't given a runnable example.

Comment: You are looking for `edgecolors= "black"`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When you use scatter plot, you set a color for both face and edge. [In the official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) you can find an additional parameter, edgecolors, which allows setting the edge color.

> edgecolors : color or sequence of color, optional, default: None
>
> If None, defaults to ‘face’
>
> If ‘face’, the edge color will always be the same as the face color.
>
> If it is ‘none’, the patch boundary will not be drawn.
>
> For non-filled markers, the edgecolors kwarg is ignored and forced to
> ‘face’ internally.

So, after all, you need only `plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors[i],edgecolors='black')`

Comment: For people like me that needed transparent points with a non-transparent border. Combined `edgecolor='b'` with `color='none'`

Answer (score 1):

you can add `edgecolors` parameter to your `plt.scatter()` method.

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors[i], edgecolors='black')
```

[Scatter plot of dataframe with edgecolor is enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvtFU.png)

Not: At least it works for me.
I am following [this course](https://www.udemy.com/course/python-for-data-science-and-machine-learning-bootcamp/).